# React dom route

Tags: reactjs

Here is my App.js code

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import About from './Pages/About';
import Contact from './Pages/Contact';
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route ,Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route Path="/About" element={<About/>}/>
            <Route Path="/Contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and Here is my About page

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>This is About</h1>
    <Link to="About">Go to About</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

React Route is not working.I installed react router Dom already.please help me to fix

Not navigation working

Comment: Please try to provide some context on the error you are getting, it will be faster to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this

```
<Link to="About">Go to About</Link>
```

to

```
<Link to="/About">Go to About</Link>
```

I have added / before the "About" in to.

Comment: not working it yet